# Robust method to detect cross and or corner contours with Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I am trying to make my own tool to robustly detect color cards in images with Python.
Every color card has a few distinct features which should be easy to recognize from the contours, amongst others the small little cross in the middle, and the four double edged corners.

From the image below I have made a contour list, and it contains 374 contours, from which i want to be able to detect the five contours of interest highlighted with red squares:

[[image: of interest]]

I have tried to apply the vertices number logic, but the contours are so small that for the corner contours, the number of vertices is differing from 4 to 5, where I actually expected 6...

Thereafter, I calculated the rotated bounding box, and if this is more or less equal in terms of width and height, I assume the contour could be of interest, unfortunately, this is the case for many contours. The following logic is currently applied, but with the number of contours detected, I will need something that defines the logic of the contours of interest much better.

Currently:

```
import numpy as np
for number, contour in enumerate(contours[78:79]):
    
    #We draw a bounding box and expect more or less a square
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contour) 
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect) 
    box = np.int0(box)
    First=[box[0][0],box[1][0],box[2][0],box[3][0]]
    Second=[box[0][1],box[1][1],box[2][1],box[3][1]]
    First_Desc=max(First)-min(First)
    Second_Desc=max(Second)-min(Second)
    
    #Next step would be to check if contour has two lines
    peri = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.04 * peri, True)
    if len(approx) == 4 or len(approx) == 5:
    
        if abs(First_Desc-Second_Desc) <= 2:
            print(First_Desc, Second_Desc)
prints:
15 14 #(being the width and height of the rotated bounding box, also returns contours not of interest)
```

Two examples:

[image: corner contour]

```
#Corner contour, from which four are present in each image
array([[[651, 732]],

       [[651, 733]],

       [[651, 734]],

       [[651, 735]],

       [[651, 736]],

       [[651, 737]],

       [[651, 738]],

       [[651, 739]],

       [[651, 740]],

       [[651, 741]],

       [[651, 742]],

       [[650, 743]],

       [[649, 743]],

       [[648, 743]],

       [[647, 743]],

       [[646, 743]],

       [[645, 743]],

       [[644, 743]],

       [[643, 743]],

       [[642, 743]],

       [[641, 743]],

       [[640, 743]],

       [[639, 743]],

       [[638, 743]],

       [[638, 744]],

       [[638, 745]],

       [[639, 746]],

       [[640, 746]],

       [[641, 746]],

       [[642, 746]],

       [[643, 746]],

       [[644, 746]],

       [[645, 746]],

       [[646, 746]],

       [[647, 746]],

       [[648, 746]],

       [[649, 746]],

       [[650, 746]],

       [[651, 746]],

       [[652, 746]],

       [[653, 745]],

       [[653, 744]],

       [[653, 743]],

       [[653, 742]],

       [[653, 741]],

       [[653, 740]],

       [[653, 739]],

       [[653, 738]],

       [[653, 737]],

       [[653, 736]],

       [[653, 735]],

       [[653, 734]],

       [[653, 733]],

       [[653, 732]],

       [[652, 732]]], dtype=int32)
```

[image: center contour]

```
Contour of cross in center of color card:
array([[[271, 427]],

       [[271, 428]],

       [[271, 429]],

       [[271, 430]],

       [[271, 431]],

       [[271, 432]],

       [[271, 433]],

       [[271, 434]],

       [[271, 435]],

       [[271, 436]],

       [[271, 437]],

       [[271, 438]],

       [[271, 439]],

       [[271, 440]],

       [[271, 441]],

       [[270, 442]],

       [[270, 443]],

       [[270, 444]],

       [[270, 445]],

       [[270, 446]],

       [[270, 447]],

       [[270, 448]],

       [[270, 449]],

       [[270, 450]],

       [[270, 451]],

       [[270, 452]],

       [[270, 453]],

       [[270, 454]],

       [[270, 455]],

       [[270, 456]],

       [[270, 457]],

       [[270, 458]],

       [[270, 459]],

       [[270, 460]],

       [[270, 461]],

       [[270, 462]],

       [[270, 463]],

       [[270, 464]],

       [[269, 465]],

       [[269, 466]],

       [[270, 467]],

       [[270, 468]],

       [[269, 469]],

       [[269, 470]],

       [[269, 471]],

       [[269, 472]],

       [[269, 473]],

       [[269, 474]],

       [[269, 475]],

       [[269, 476]],

       [[269, 477]],

       [[269, 478]],

       [[269, 479]],

       [[269, 480]],

       [[269, 481]],

       [[269, 482]],

       [[269, 483]],

       [[269, 484]],

       [[269, 485]],

       [[269, 486]],

       [[269, 487]],

       [[269, 488]],

       [[269, 489]],

       [[269, 490]],

       [[269, 491]],

       [[269, 492]],

       [[269, 493]],

       [[268, 494]],

       [[268, 495]],

       [[268, 496]],

       [[268, 497]],

       [[268, 498]],

       [[268, 499]],

       [[269, 500]],

       [[269, 501]],

       [[270, 501]],

       [[271, 501]],

       [[272, 501]],

       [[273, 501]],

       [[274, 501]],

       [[275, 502]],

       [[276, 502]],

       [[277, 502]],

       [[278, 502]],

       [[279, 502]],

       [[280, 502]],

       [[281, 502]],

       [[282, 502]],

       [[283, 502]],

       [[284, 502]],

       [[285, 502]],

       [[286, 502]],

       [[287, 502]],

       [[288, 502]],

       [[289, 503]],

       [[290, 503]],

       [[291, 503]],

       [[292, 503]],

       [[293, 503]],

       [[294, 503]],

       [[295, 503]],

       [[296, 503]],

       [[297, 503]],

       [[298, 503]],

       [[299, 503]],

       [[300, 504]],

       [[301, 504]],

       [[302, 503]],

       [[303, 503]],

       [[304, 504]],

       [[305, 504]],

       [[306, 504]],

       [[307, 504]],

       [[308, 504]],

       [[309, 504]],

       [[310, 504]],

       [[311, 504]],

       [[312, 504]],

       [[313, 504]],

       [[314, 504]],

       [[315, 504]],

       [[316, 504]],

       [[317, 504]],

       [[318, 504]],

       [[319, 505]],

       [[320, 505]],

       [[321, 505]],

       [[322, 505]],

       [[323, 505]],

       [[324, 505]],

       [[325, 505]],

       [[326, 505]],

       [[327, 505]],

       [[328, 505]],

       [[329, 505]],

       [[330, 505]],

       [[331, 505]],

       [[332, 505]],

       [[333, 505]],

       [[334, 506]],

       [[335, 506]],

       [[336, 506]],

       [[337, 506]],

       [[338, 506]],

       [[339, 506]],

       [[340, 506]],

       [[341, 506]],

       [[342, 506]],

       [[343, 506]],

       [[344, 506]],

       [[345, 506]],

       [[346, 506]],

       [[347, 506]],

       [[347, 505]],

       [[347, 504]],

       [[347, 503]],

       [[347, 502]],

       [[347, 501]],

       [[347, 500]],

       [[347, 499]],

       [[347, 498]],

       [[347, 497]],

       [[347, 496]],

       [[347, 495]],

       [[347, 494]],

       [[347, 493]],

       [[347, 492]],

       [[347, 491]],

       [[347, 490]],

       [[347, 489]],

       [[347, 488]],

       [[347, 487]],

       [[347, 486]],

       [[347, 485]],

       [[347, 484]],

       [[347, 483]],

       [[347, 482]],

       [[347, 481]],

       [[347, 480]],

       [[347, 479]],

       [[347, 478]],

       [[347, 477]],

       [[348, 476]],

       [[348, 475]],

       [[348, 474]],

       [[348, 473]],

       [[348, 472]],

       [[348, 471]],

       [[348, 470]],

       [[348, 469]],

       [[348, 468]],

       [[348, 467]],

       [[348, 466]],

       [[348, 465]],

       [[348, 464]],

       [[348, 463]],

       [[348, 462]],

       [[348, 461]],

       [[348, 460]],

       [[348, 459]],

       [[348, 458]],

       [[348, 457]],

       [[348, 456]],

       [[348, 455]],

       [[348, 454]],

       [[348, 453]],

       [[348, 452]],

       [[348, 451]],

       [[349, 450]],

       [[349, 449]],

       [[349, 448]],

       [[349, 447]],

       [[348, 446]],

       [[349, 445]],

       [[349, 444]],

       [[349, 443]],

       [[349, 442]],

       [[349, 441]],

       [[349, 440]],

       [[349, 439]],

       [[349, 438]],

       [[349, 437]],

       [[349, 436]],

       [[349, 435]],

       [[349, 434]],

       [[349, 433]],

       [[349, 432]],

       [[348, 432]],

       [[347, 432]],

       [[346, 432]],

       [[345, 431]],

       [[344, 431]],

       [[343, 431]],

       [[342, 431]],

       [[341, 431]],

       [[340, 431]],

       [[339, 431]],

       [[338, 431]],

       [[337, 431]],

       [[336, 431]],

       [[335, 431]],

       [[334, 431]],

       [[333, 431]],

       [[332, 431]],

       [[331, 431]],

       [[330, 431]],

       [[329, 431]],

       [[328, 431]],

       [[327, 430]],

       [[326, 430]],

       [[325, 430]],

       [[324, 430]],

       [[323, 430]],

       [[322, 430]],

       [[321, 430]],

       [[320, 430]],

       [[319, 430]],

       [[318, 430]],

       [[317, 430]],

       [[316, 429]],

       [[315, 429]],

       [[314, 429]],

       [[313, 429]],

       [[312, 429]],

       [[311, 429]],

       [[310, 429]],

       [[309, 429]],

       [[308, 429]],

       [[307, 429]],

       [[306, 429]],

       [[305, 429]],

       [[304, 429]],

       [[303, 429]],

       [[302, 429]],

       [[301, 429]],

       [[300, 429]],

       [[299, 429]],

       [[298, 428]],

       [[297, 428]],

       [[296, 428]],

       [[295, 428]],

       [[294, 428]],

       [[293, 428]],

       [[292, 428]],

       [[291, 428]],

       [[290, 428]],

       [[289, 428]],

       [[288, 428]],

       [[287, 427]],

       [[286, 427]],

       [[285, 427]],

       [[284, 427]],

       [[283, 427]],

       [[282, 427]],

       [[281, 427]],

       [[280, 427]],

       [[279, 427]],

       [[278, 427]],

       [[277, 427]],

       [[276, 427]],

       [[275, 427]],

       [[274, 427]],

       [[273, 427]],

       [[272, 427]]], dtype=int32)
```

Raw image for reproducibility (binary)
[image: raw_image]

Comment: maybe houghlines with max length. Then find the intersections of the lines.

Comment: First I would suggest you correct the rotation of the whole image so that the boxes an fiducially are more vertical and horizontal lines. Then once you use contours to find the right size objects and or locations relative to the bounds of the main color checker background, you can crop them and then use either template matching or hit-or-miss morphology to decide if they are ficucials or crosses (or perhaps shape matching will be adequate, though your features being so small that may not work)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Rotating the image is not possible, I want to color correct large batches of images, sometimes the color card will be a bit rotated, or perhaps largely rotated. This is where software such as plantcv fails: (pcv.transform.find_color_card) and what I try to solve.

Comment: If your images are similar, then you should be able to get the contour of the color card and then its rotated bounding box (cv2.minAreaRect) from the contour. Then from the rotated bounding box, you can get the angle and rotate the image to correct its orientation.  Is this not possible for your images?

Comment: There are multiple squares in the full image by default, sometimes rectangles, but I think you are on to something here. Perhaps we can filter the contours with more or less the width:height ratio corresponding to the color card, containing at least two or three almost perfect squares. To find the color card contour though, we need to invert the image, meaning the perfect squares within the color card will be lost!

Comment: You only have to invert to get the bounding rectangle. You can use that to rotated the original.